# Insert data to cpanel database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm working on this project where users can sign up for the newsletter and their names get added to the online database. I am using the online database (CPanel - PhPMyAdmin) I've been stuck on what type of code am I supposed to use to add this data from my form to the database.

This is what I have so far and I'm not quite sure how to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

ALSO: I'm using Bootstrap3 and jquery/ajax

```
<div id="newsletter" class="container-fluid text-center">
            <h3>NEWSLETTER</h3>

            <form id="signup-form" action="" method="">
              <div class="input-prepend" ><span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <label for="name">Your Full Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="your full name" size="40" style="color:black;" class="validate" required>
              </div>

              <div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <label for="email">Your Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="your@email.com" size="40" style="color:black;"class="validate" required>
              </div>

              <button id="sub" type="submit" class="btn btn-large"> Sign Up!</button>
            </form>
            <br/>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use Ajax**

Example -

```
$('#button').click(function() {//give id of submit button 
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();//get value you need to post
    var val2 = $('#text2').val();//get value you need to post
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'process.php',
        data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);//responce you recevied 
        }
    }); });
```

Get both values using Post method. Perform your action and send true false in the result.

**---------------Explaning in deep with new example----------------**

**HTML File: ajaxsubmit.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Submit Form Using AJAX and jQuery</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/refreshform.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="mainform">
<h2>Submit Form Using AJAX and jQuery</h2> <!-- Required div Starts Here -->
<div id="form">
<h3>Fill Your Information !</h3>
<div>
<label>Name :</label>
<input id="name" type="text">
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="email" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="password" type="password">
<label>Contact No :</label>
<input id="contact" type="text">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP File: ajaxsubmit.php**

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server..
$db = mysql_select_db("mydba", $connection); // Selecting Database
//Fetching Values from URL
$name2=$_POST['name1'];
$email2=$_POST['email1'];
$password2=$_POST['password1'];
$contact2=$_POST['contact1'];
//Insert query
$query = mysql_query("insert into form_element(name, email, password, contact) values ('$name2', '$email2', '$password2','$contact2')");
echo "Form Submitted Succesfully";
mysql_close($connection); // Connection Closed
?>
```

**jQuery File: script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
var name = $("#name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var password = $("#password").val();
var contact = $("#contact").val();
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
var dataString = 'name1='+ name + '&email1='+ email + '&password1='+ password + '&contact1='+ contact;
if(name==''||email==''||password==''||contact=='')
{
alert("Please Fill All Fields");
}
else
{
// AJAX Code To Submit Form.
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "ajaxsubmit.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(result){
alert(result);
}
});
}
return false;
});
});
```

**MY-SQL Code Segment:**

```
CREATE DATABASE mydba;
CREATE TABLE form_element(
id int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
email varchar(255) NOT NULL,
password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
contact varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: What's the process.php for?

Comment: I didn't get you exactly about what process.php ? I am updating my answer to guide what's written in it according to your question

Comment: Oh i don't really have any php files atm so i'm confused on what it's for

Comment: Thank you!! I got it! :D

Comment: Sorry one question! when i click submit it shows the ajaxsubmit.php code as alert not the result? where am i going wrong?